# Attaching file to email using ContentProvider isn't working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I want to attach a file I generate on runtime.

Runtime flow:

1. Create intent
2. Create a file under `cacheDir`
3. Add file as `content://` extra to the intent
4. Start chooser and select Gmail
5. expect `openFile()` to be called and allow access
6. Gmail opens with no attachment

However, **`openFile()` isn't called.**

Here is the relevant code:

Create an intent and add extras:

```
public static void contact(Activity activity, String message) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

    String version = Version.appVersion(activity);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{activity.getString(R.string.contact_email)});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.app_name)+" ("+version+")");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    addInfoAttachment(emailIntent, activity);

    String title = activity.getString(R.string.string_select_email_app);
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));
}
```

Create the cached file:

```
public static void createCachedFile(Context context, String fileName,
                                    String content) throws IOException 
{
    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator
            + fileName);
    cacheFile.delete();
    cacheFile.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw);
    pw.println(content);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

Add the file to the intent:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + File.separator + REPORT_INFO_FILE_NAME));
```

Overriding `ContentProvider`:  **(not called)**

```
public class LogFileProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String TAG = "LogFileProvider";

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.domain.appName.LogFileProvider";

    private UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "*", 1);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Log.v(TAG, "openFile Called with uri: '" + uri + "'." + uri.getLastPathSegment());

        // Check incoming Uri against the matcher
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {

            // If it returns 1 - then it matches the Uri defined in onCreate
            case 1:
                String fileLocation = getContext().getCacheDir() + File.separator
                        + uri.getLastPathSegment();
                return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(
                        fileLocation), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);

            default:
                Log.v(TAG, "Unsupported uri: '" + uri + "'.");
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Unsupported uri: "
                        + uri.toString());
        }
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Not supported / used / required for this example
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s,
                      String[] as) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String s, String[] as1,
                        String s1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name=".LogFileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.domain.appName.LogFileProvider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`. As it stands, the recipient has no rights to access that content.

You might consider using `FileProvider` rather than bothering with your own. Some clients will expect the provider to do more than what you have (e.g., respond to `query()` for the `OpenableColumns`, respond to `getType()` with the actual MIME type).

Comment: You are obviously right. I've change `LogFileProvider` to extend `FileProvider`, (not it's empty) added the missing permission, but still nothing. I've also tried adding meta-data of `FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS` to the `provider` under the manifest. Is there any web-page with a good example?

Comment: @SagiLow: I don't have an `ACTION_SEND` `FileProvider` sample, though I should in a couple of weeks. For `FileProvider` more generally, [this uses it for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Camera/FileProvider) and [this uses it for `ACTION_VIEW`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Notifications/Foreground).